# Alamofire4 migration, Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

After spending weeks migrating all my Alamofire code to AF4/Swift3, I finally fixed all the complier errors due to Alamofire Function changes, but now when I try to build a I get a whole bunch of these Apple Mach-O errors.

There's at least 29 of them and they all have either Alamofire or AlamofireImage in them (aside from the last one which is "Linker command failed with exit code 1"). I don't have a clue of what to do here, I'll post any extra info needed, can anyone help me out here?

edit: Here are the first 3 errors, I copied only the parts highlighted in red. I will post the full log if necessary but its huge. Maybe this is enough for someone to figure out what's going on, if not, let me know!

All errors are under `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`

```
  "Alamofire.DataRequest.validate <A where A: Swift.Sequence, A.Iterator.Element == Swift.Int> (statusCode : A) -> Self", referenced from:
```

--

```
"Alamofire.(request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest).(default argument 1)", referenced from:
```

--

```
"Alamofire.(upload (multipartFormData : (Alamofire.MultipartFormData) -> (), usingThreshold : Swift.UInt64, to : Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?, encodingCompletion : (Alamofire.SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) -> ()?) -> ()).(default argument 1)", referenced from:
```

Comment: Did you tried to command + shift + K and rebuild your pj ?
And post your build error log.

Comment: yes, and would you like the whole error log? because like I said its huge. All the errors are under `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick for me at least isn't to clean build, but to "Clean Build Folder". Open the Product menu drop down in Xcode and hold Option, and "Clean" turns into "Clean Build Folder"