# ios- Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I used `pod deintegrate` on my xCode project and then when I subsequently did `pod install`, I get the following Buildtime errors.

I have no idea why this is happening, it was working before I deintegrated.
  Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

I've tried cleaning the project and deleting and re-adding the ViewController, which was suggested in other answers. Did not work.

```
  "type metadata accessor for Alamofire.Result", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.(request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest).(default argument 1)", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.(request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest).(default argument 2)", referenced from:

  "SwiftyJSON.JSON.init (Any) -> SwiftyJSON.JSON", referenced from:

  "protocol witness table for Swift.Int : SwiftyJSON.JSONSubscriptType in SwiftyJSON", referenced from:

  "SwiftyJSON.JSON.subscript.getter : ([SwiftyJSON.JSONSubscriptType]...) -> SwiftyJSON.JSON", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.Result.value.getter : A?", referenced from:

  "protocol witness table for Swift.String : Alamofire.URLConvertible in Alamofire", referenced from:

  "protocol descriptor for SwiftyJSON.JSONSubscriptType", referenced from:

  "protocol witness table for Alamofire.JSONEncoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding in Alamofire", referenced from:

  "SwiftyJSON.JSON.arrayValue.getter : [SwiftyJSON.JSON]", referenced from:

  "static Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default.getter : Alamofire.JSONEncoding", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.(request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest).(default argument 3)", referenced from:

  "type metadata for Alamofire.JSONEncoding", referenced from:

  "static SwiftyJSON.JSON.null.getter : SwiftyJSON.JSON", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.(request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest).(default argument 4)", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method : Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?) -> Alamofire.DataRequest", referenced from:

  "type metadata for SwiftyJSON.JSON", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.DataRequest.(responseJSON (queue : __ObjC.DispatchQueue?, options : __ObjC.JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions, completionHandler : (Alamofire.DataResponse<Any>) -> ()) -> Self).(default argument 0)", referenced from:

  "protocol witness table for Swift.String : SwiftyJSON.JSONSubscriptType in SwiftyJSON", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.DataRequest.(responseJSON (queue : __ObjC.DispatchQueue?, options : __ObjC.JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions, completionHandler : (Alamofire.DataResponse<Any>) -> ()) -> Self).(default argument 1)", referenced from:

  "Alamofire.DataRequest.responseJSON (queue : __ObjC.DispatchQueue?, options : __ObjC.JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions, completionHandler : (Alamofire.DataResponse<Any>) -> ()) -> Self", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

Comment: calvocruz your framework is not installed properly.Can you show your pod file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it so happens, the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058835/alamofire4-migration-apple-mach-o-linker-id-error) worked for me!

Open the Product menu drop down in Xcode and hold Option, and "Clean" turns into "Clean Build Folder"